# How can I calculate the probability of multiple events assuming they may or may not be independent?

Tags: conditional-probability

I have this problem in my work. Assume I have multiple events, say A, B, C. **I want to calculate probability P(ABC)** But among A,B,C some of them may or may not be dependent to each other.

With regards to my work scenario, I have the values of probability P(A), P(B), P(C), and also probabilities like P(A|BC), P(B|AC),P(C|AB), P(A|C), P(B|C),P(A|B) etc. Since they are not independent, I can not use P(A,B,C)=P(A)*P(B)*P(C).

So I need to use conditional probability: P(ABC)=P(A|BC)*P(BC)=P(A|BC)*P(B|C)*P(C)
Is this correct?

Comment: Question is too vague. Is X = $A\cap B\cap C$ and what exactly is it you know? I suspect you need to look at Baye's Theorem, which will allow you to calculate a probability given enough known conditional probabilities.

Comment: Yes I think it is X = A∩B∩C in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have that $$
  P(X \cap Y) = P(X \mid Y)P(Y) = P(Y \mid X)P(X)
$$
Applying that twice (first with $X=C,Y=A\cap B$, then with $X=B,Y=A$) yields $$
P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(C \mid A \cap B)P(A \cap B) = P(C \mid A \cap B)P(B \mid A)P(A) \text{.}
$$
In plain english, this means that the probability that $A,B$ and $C$ occurs is the probability that $A$ occurs, times the probability that $B$ also occurs knowing that $A$ already occured, times the probability that $C$ occurs knowing that $A,B$ already occured.